# SQLlite: strange "Abort due to constraint violation"

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to rename a column of a table. I have a lot of tables with the word "`couleur`" and I renamed "manually" to "`bulle`".

I've successfully renamed `main_groupecouleurs` to `main_groupebulles`. Now i'm working on `main_groupe`. I'm trying to rename `groupe_couleurs_id` to `groupe_bulles_id`

The SQL is quite self-explaining:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DROP INDEX main_groupe_fc5cee5b;
CREATE TABLE main_groupe7e12
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    exemple TEXT,
    groupe_bulles_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    reference TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (groupe_bulles_id) REFERENCES main_groupebulles(id)
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX main_groupe_fc5cee5b ON main_groupe7e12 (groupe_bulles_id);
INSERT INTO main_groupe7e12(id, description, exemple, groupe_bulles_id, reference)
                     SELECT id, description, exemple, groupe_couleurs_id, reference
                     FROM main_groupe;
DROP TABLE main_groupe;
ALTER TABLE main_groupe7e12 RENAME TO main_groupe;
COMMIT;
```

When I run it, I get:

```
[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation
    (UNIQUE constraint failed: main_groupe7e12.groupe_bulles_id)
```

This means (I think I'm wrong here but I dont know what I'm missing) that it tries to insert some `groupe_couleurs_id` that are **not** in the referring table (= `main_groupebulles`). Thus I tried to see in the original table the problem:

```
SELECT * FROM main_groupe WHERE groupe_couleurs_id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM main_groupebulles
);
```

I got *no rows*! What am I missing?

Comment: You have an `unique` index - do you have duplicates in `groupe_couleurs_id`?

Comment: Ok I got your question, but my original table is filled with more that 500 rows which all refer to 12 "`groupe_couleurs`" so the `groupe_couleurs_id` index should *not* be unique, otherwise it would not have been possible to insert all those rows... and the SQL you see in my question comes from the "right click->modify table" of my PyCharm program... unless i'm missing something?

Comment: Use something like `select groupe_couleurs_id from main_groupe group by groupe_couleurs_id having count(*) > 1;` to find the dupes.

Comment: With your query I have tons of result rows

Comment: I've removed the word "`unique`" and it worked, thank you, may I ask you to answer below so I could check your answer as valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `UNIQUE` index on your `groupe_bulles_id` column but based on the comments, there are a lot of valid duplicate values for that column coming from `main_groupe.groupe_couleus_id` and that causes the constraint violation.

Since having duplicate values is what you want, remove the `UNIQUE` from the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ...`.

Comment: I just dont understand how this could be possible... I guess that SQLite doesnt handle a lot of constraints.... like unique and I guess ON DELETE CASCADE and all basic stuff like that...